# Using Ymodem file transfer in c#

Tags: c#, serial-port

I am currently searching for an idea to use a ymodem communication on one of my software using c# Framework .NET 2.0.

Does somebody have a solution to do ymodem file transfer in C# ? Because I haven't found anything for now...

Thank you by advance.

Joe

Answer (score 1):

There is a project on google code (http://code.google.com/p/ymodemdotnet/). I can not speak to it's quality. It would be a start at least.

Comment: I'm assuming that Joe wants to implement YModem on both ends of the cable, and in this case I believe ymodemdotnet falls short.  It looks like a transmit-only implementation.  I am currently looking for something, but think I will also have to roll my own .NET library for this.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an Ymodem implementation I wrote.
It's still far from perfect, but it works, commented and simple.
https://sites.google.com/site/adamficsor1024/home/programming/xymodem

Comment: You should add some representative code to this post from the link. Links might get broken eventually, resulting in loss of infomration.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about YModem, but original XModem (not the non-standard 1k version) is pretty easy to code up on your own with a SOH byte, block#, block, and small checksum.

Comment: If I could find a library or something It should better :)

Comment: Yea, I suppose. It is incredibly simple. With a spec in hand, you could be able to do it a few hours. Honest. Its simple. Did I say that it is simple?